# Is there any relationship between beat frequency and temperature

Tags: waves, temperature, frequency

at 51°C the beat frequency is 4Hz but then temperature decreased to 16°C. At 16°C the beat frequency is 1Hz what is the frequency of tuning fork?

I dont want the answer i need a explanation

Comment: I assume you're asking about sound.  Can you give any more detail?  Your question is pretty vague as it stands.

Comment: @M.Enns ok i hope now it is clear